# Block cipher modes used in real life

Tags: block-cipher, symmetric

There is a number of block cipher modes, including ECB, CBC, CFB, OFB, CTR and others.
After reading "Serious Cryptography. A Practical Introduction to Modern Encryption" by Jean-Philippe Aumasson, where the author described CFB and OFB as folklore which no one really uses,
I am curious which ones are most commonly used in the real world?
I think the one I come across most often would be CBC.
Would anyone be able to share some stats (which I didn't manage to get to), or make and educated quess?

Comment: CFB is the encryption mode of by PGP/GPG, that's not exactly folklore which no one really uses. AES is very much used in CTR mode, and derivatives of that for authenticated encryption. That's not an answer, for I have no stats.

Comment: I would say in the future AES-GCM-SIV will be the beast.

Comment: AES-GCM, with indeed AES-CTR as encryption cipher is also used in TLS 1.3. Although TLS 1.2 is still very actively used (AES / CBC), I guess that CTR mode will become even more prevalent in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

CTR is the most used one with some additional authentication

Comment: Could you please back up your answer with some references?